# No me deja instalar nuevos paquetes la nueva version de React 18

Tags: reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que deseo instalar un paquete que no sea reciente me sale este error y no puedo seguir avanzando en mi proyecto, estoy realizando una aplicacion con React. En el package me sale esta version pero en la imagen del error me indica 18.2. React": "^18.1.0", "react-dom": "^18.1.0". Ademas que me sale deprecated y varios warning cada vez que levanto la aplicacion. Alguien sabe algo sobre este error? Muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: ¿Leíste el error? Especialmente la parte en la que te dice cómo corregirlo. Por cierto, no todos pueden ver las imágenes: los mensajes de error deben ir _como texto, con formato_.

Answer (score 0):

tenes que borrar el paquete de `node_modules` y el `package.json` e instalar los paquetes correpondientes si no funciona asi, tambien proba borrar el cache

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/387217)